# Trouble with the unmixing matrix from fastica toolbox in Matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, signal-processing

I'm using the FastIca toolbox (https://research.ics.aalto.fi/ica/fastica/) but am confused about the orientation of the resulting W (separating/unmixing) matrix.

Let X be a n x B matrix where n is the number of signals in a data set and B is the number of time points sampled at.

I've been calculating the W matrix using:

```
[A,W] = fastica(X)
```

However, because W is a n x n matrix I can't tell how it is oriented and whether to use W or its transpose (W.') in subsequent calculations, and can't seem to find a clear answer in the documentation.

To help me get my bearings, is fastica maximising the independence in the rows of Y where Y = W.'X ***or*** Y = WX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `Y=W*X`. To be sure, you can reduce the number of component to estimate and then `W` should no longer be square:

```
[A,W] = fastica(X,'numOfIC',2)
```

If `W` is of size `2xn` then `Y=W*X`. Else `W` has a size nx2 and `Y=W'*X`